# Understanding JavaPairRDD.reduceByKey function

Tags: java, apache-spark, functional-programming

I came across follow code snippet of Apache Spark:

```
JavaRDD<String> lines = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext()).textFile("src\\main\\resources\\data.txt");
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = lines.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2(s, 1));
System.out.println(pairs.collect());
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
System.out.println("Reduced data: " + counts.collect());
```

My data.txt is as follows:

```
Mahesh
Mahesh
Ganesh
Ashok
Abnave
Ganesh
Mahesh
```

The output is:

```
[(Mahesh,1), (Mahesh,1), (Ganesh,1), (Ashok,1), (Abnave,1), (Ganesh,1), (Mahesh,1)]
Reduced data: [(Ganesh,2), (Abnave,1), (Mahesh,3), (Ashok,1)]
```

While I understand how first line of output is obtained, I dont understand how second line is obtained, that is how `JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts` is formed by `reduceByKey`.

I found that the [signature](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#reduceByKey(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2)) of `reduceByKey()` is as follows:

```
public JavaPairRDD<K,V> reduceByKey(Function2<V,V,V> func)
```

The [signature](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function2.html#call(T1, T2)) of `Function2.call()` is as follows:

```
R call(T1 v1, T2 v2) throws Exception
```

The explanation of `reduceByKey()` reads as follows:

> Merge the values for each key using an associative reduce function. This will also perform the merging locally on each mapper before sending results to a reducer, similarly to a "combiner" in MapReduce. Output will be hash-partitioned with the existing partitioner/ parallelism level.

Now this explanation sounds somewhat confusing to me. May be there is something more to the functionality of `reduceByKey()`. By looking at input and output to `reduceByKey()` and `Function2.call()`, I feel somehow `reducebyKey()` sends values of same keys to `call()` in pairs. But that simply does not sound clear. Can anyone explain what precisely how `reduceByKey()` and `Function2.call()` works together?

Answer (score 2):

As its name implies, `reduceByKey()` reduces data based on the lambda function you pass to it.

In your example, this function is a simple adder: for `a` and `b`, return `a + b`. 
The best way to understand how the result is formed is to imagine what happens internally. The `ByKey()` part groups your records based on their key values. In your example, you'll have 4 different sets of pairs:

Set 1: `((Mahesh, 1), (Mahesh, 1), (Mahesh, 1))`

Set 2: `((Ganesh, 1), (Ganesh, 1))`

Set 3: `((Ashok, 1))`

Set 4: `((Abnave, 1))`

Now, the `reduce` part will try to reduce the previous 4 sets using the lambda function (the adder):

For Set 1: (Mahesh, 1 + 1 + 1) -> (Mahesh, 3)

For Set 2: (Ganesh, 1 + 1) -> (Ganesh, 2)

For Set 3: (Ashok , 1) -> (Ashok, 1) (nothing to add)

For Set 4: (Abnave, 1) -> (Abnave, 1) (nothing to add)

Functions signatures can be sometimes confusing as they tend to be more generic.

Comment: yeah a logic like this can built to simplify "interpretation", but just wanted to know how exactly calls to that lambda is made by `reduceByKey`. Because the lambda accepts only two parameters and definitely it cannot be passed three 1s as for key `Mahesh`. But thats how the any `reduce` works. Passing two params at once, then ther earlier result and next param, right? Now just guesssing how it is deciding what seed to pass to lambda when there is only one param, that is, one 1 as in case of `Ashok` and `Abnave`.

Comment: Reducing is a folding operation. The lambda doesn't receive 3 parameters in fact, only 2. It adds them and keeps going with the previous result. 3 1s means 1 + 1, then (1 + 1) + 1, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that you probably understand `groupByKey`? `groupByKey` groups all values for a certain key into a list (or iterable) so that you can do something with that - like, say, sum (or count) the values. Basically, what `sum` does is to *reduce* a list of many values into a single value. It does so by iteratively adding *two* values to yield *one* value and that is what `Function2` needs to do when you write your own. It needs to take in two values and return one value.

`ReduceByKey` does the same as a `groupByKey`, BUT it does what is called a *"map-side reduce"* before shuffling data around. Because Spark distributes data across many different machines to allow for parallel processing, there is no guarantee that data with the same key is placed on the same machine. Spark thus has to shuffle data around, and the more data that needs to be shuffled the longer our computations will take, so it's a good idea to shuffle as little data as needed.

In a *map-side reduce*, Spark will first sum all the values for a given key *locally* on the executors before it sends (shuffles) the result around for the final sum to be computed. This means that much less data - a single value instead of a list of values - needs to be send between the different machines in the cluster and for this reason, `reduceByKey` is most often preferable to a `groupByKey`.

For a more detailed description, I can recommend [this article](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)  :)